# Slow table rendering

Tags: angular, performance, rendering, ngfor

I'm working on an application displaying multiple tables.
The constraint I have is to display everything in one single page.
I've manage to limit the window to 30 days (60 columns).
Unfortunately, I cannot limit the number of lines (neither the number of tables) because the all purpose of the application is to have everything without reload.

So far, the application contains 15 tables with 10 lines on average which makes a total of 9 000 cells.
Some user are seeing "Warning Unresponsive script" when they want to see everything at the same time.

I went through the basic already :

- OnPush
- trackby

I have isolated the source of latency which is the ngFor displaying the content. Each cell has a click, mouseenter, mouseleave, dblclick, ngClass and ngStyle binding which I believe to be the source of my issue.

I have monitored the time a detectChanges takes (env local): 1.5 seconds on chrome. The result is worst on Firefox 5X (User's main browser), Edge gave up and I'm not displaying everything ...

When I remove all events, the detectChanges drops to 400ms on chrome (except for the first time the app loads).

**Tests :**

I tested in a production like environment (ng build --prod --aot) and with a lot more data .

- Chrome : between 1.5-2s each refresh
- Firefox : around 6s each refresh (and "Warning Unresponsive script")

I have used the profiling tools available on Firefox dev and Chrome to find the issue's origin and it seems to be related to rendering work (Update Layer tree ...)

Here are the packages :

```
   "@angular/animations": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.2",
    "@covalent/core": "1.0.0-beta.5-1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.66",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "angular2-drag-scroll": "^1.3.5",
    "angular2-material-datepicker": "^0.5.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "c3": "^0.4.13",
    "cheet.js": "^0.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "4.9.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hover.css": "^2.2.0",
    "jQuery.print": "^1.5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "md-multiselect": "0.0.1-alpha.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.2",
    "moment-business": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
```

The only workaround so far is a infinite scroll. 
Problem is in certain condition, I can have one single table with 100 lines which will most certainly raise the same issue as having 10 tables of 10 lines.

What are my options here ?

[UPDATE] : Profiler screenshot

[Profiler screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHGEp.jpg)

In the XHR LOAD, the detectchanges takes 99% of 2s
On the right, the small spaced lines are the "update layer tree".
When I remove my css, the space between them disappear  but I cannot find the exact css producing this behavior

Comment: what happens if you remove mouseenter, mouseleave, dblclick, ngClass and ngStyle binding from each cell?

Comment: @RenéWinkler I added the details to the original post